# Name for sequence that begins and ends with the same element?

Tags: sequences-and-series, definition

Is there a name for a sequence $(a_1,a_2,...,a_k)\in{A^k}$ where $a_1=a_k$?

Comment: I don't know of any term for such a sequence in a general setting. If this notion is important in a proof, make up a term. "Circular", for example, or "cyclic".

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I have modified it in this way.

Comment: You're welcome. I still had time to remove that advice :)

Comment: A subclass, where reading backwards gives the same sequence, is called *palindromic*. So $a_1=a_k$, $a_2=a_{k-1}$ until the middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would call it a *cyclic* sequence, but I would still give an actual definition, as you have.